# BizTalk WCF SQL adapter receiving timeout trying to get a connection from the pool

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I have an extremely simple BizTalk orchestration that takes a HIPAA 837 file in, breaks it into its individual claims, and saves the complete xml message to the database. I have a WCF SQL send port that calls a stored procedure to do this... the proc just does an insert with no return value. The problem is that I keep (randomly) getting the timeout error:

Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.InvalidUriException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I just tried this with a small file - only 5 individual claims in it (so I should only need 5 connections from the pool, right?). The BT server has been doing nothing else for the past 10 hours (no messages processed). Yet I still received this error... My MaxConnectionPoolSize is set to 100, so that means 100 connections have been held open and idle for at least 10 hours ?? What's going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look [here](http://numbereightwired.blogspot.com/2010/11/wcf-sql-adapter-times-out-with.html) or [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkr2adapters/thread/bfc2c635-de90-453b-b9ce-d2bd44548efd/).  To be honest the WCF SQL adapter is very picky and quirky as to what SQL it works well with and what it doesn't.  I typically look for a custom solution for inserting into SQL to have more control over the inserts or updates without having to write my SQL specific for the SQL adapter.  I find if I'm inserting or updating more than one table or returning a complex records, I avoid the WCF SQL adapter.

If that's not an option, look at re-writing your SQL.